# confusion, this-pointer and events in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object which I would like to be able to handle some interactive features. It's a bit tricky to describe the scenario in a simple way so hopefully it'll not get all out of hand here.

my object looks something like

```
myobject = function() {
    this.initialize = function() {
        // HERE this = the myobject instance
        var test = document.createElement('div');
        test.onmousedown = this.mousedown;
    }
    this.mousedown = function(e) {
        // HERE this = the calling div-element
    }
}
```

So my problem is basically that `this` will not be an `myobject` instance when `this.mousedown(e)` is called, it will rather be the caller (if the terminology is correct?) in this case it is the div I created and put in a variable called `test` above.

I would like to have access to the instance on which the method is being run (as I believe that to be the `mousedown` method I created).

This far I have had some ideas which I have tried out:

- create a `data-` attribute on the `div` containing the `this` object and operate on that.
- sending the this pointer as an argument along with `e` to `this.mousedown(e)`

It's all I can think of now hope it makes sence.

Comment: Are you aware that your sample code is invalid JS?  `funciton () { ... }` is a method call to a function named "funciton" followed by an unrelated block of statements.  `this.initialize() { ... }` is similarly a method call followed by an unrelated block. as is `this.mousedown() { ... }`.  Post semicolon insertion, this code is equivalent to `myobject = funciton(); this.initialize(); var test = ...; test.onmousedown = this.mousedown; this.mousedown();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a copy when you first instantiate the object:

```
var myobject = function() {
    var self = this;    
    this.initialize() {
        // HERE this = the myobject instance
        var test = document.createElement('div');
        test.onmousedown = this.mousedown;
    }
    this.mousedown(e) {
        // HERE this = the calling div-element
        // use self instead of this
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kenneth that does solve my problem as far as I can see, I think most of all I were a bit confused when trying to use `this` in the call-back functions and when I looked inside to see why it weren't working I realized that `this` in the context weren't the js-object at all. But the solution you prompted works fine for me thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Happy to help. I imagine the errors in your script come from copying the code to SO. If not, please revise Mike's comment

Comment: Indeed the problems were because I wrote the example just from the top of my head and weren't careful to type a working example. I think I've edited it and that it should be correct now as long as I didn't missinterpret the comment about what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to make a 'self' var that you refer to in the callback:

```
myobject = funciton() {
    var self = this;
    this.initialize() {
        //use self to refer to myobject
        self.mousedown(e);
    }
    this.mousedown(e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: i'll admit i've no idea what you're trying to do with .mousedown - but as @Kenneth also pointed out, this how you can avoid 'this' confusion.

Comment: `funciton()` should be `function()` I believe

Comment: for sure... i copied the code and gave an example of how to use 'self'